# MacOS: different treatment of IDEs and terminal when running code?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, ide, sublimetext3

I am having a problem with a python IDE (Sublime) on macos when trying to use ktinter:

I set up a clean mac and installed Python 3.7 via the normal installer (with the box ticked to install tkinter)

The problem I am having now is this: When I write code in Sublime and try to run it within the IDE (Sublime -> Tools -> Build) I get an error message.

Code

```
import tkinter as tk
tk._test()
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christiankoch/Desktop/sys.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter as tk
ImportError: No module named tkinter
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/christiankoch/Desktop/sys.py"]
[dir: /Users/christiankoch/Desktop]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

However, when I just save the file and run it in the terminal everything works fine and I see the test window.

In the terminal

```
python3 test.py
```

So ultimately I am confused about different outcomes of the two approaches. When I use Sublime on Windows it works perfectly fine; and even using pyCharm on macos works for tkinter. So I am confused what the problem is.

Comment: That could be some issue with import paths. Try adding `import sys` and `print(sys.path)` to your script, and compare output from sublime vs. command line.

Comment: Also, try `print(sys.version)` just to be sure you are running the same version of Python. Could you by any chance have had Python 2 preinstalled on the machine? (in Python 2, tkinter module was called Tkinter, and `import tkinter` would throw exactly this error)

Comment: It does work when I write 'import Tkinter', thank you so much! Although, can I force sublime to use python 3?

Answer (score 0):

When you run file.py from the console, the executable as specified in the environment variables is used by default. 
In sublime you probably using a build system, that points to another environment/ executable. You should have a look at https://youtu.be/xqcTfplzr7c
And follow the instructions.

Comment: That explained and fixed it! Thank you so much for the answer.